# magento 2 get CMS page URL path

Tags: magento2, url, cms

In magento 2.4.3, How to get the current page URL in block file. I tried [this](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-get-base-url-and-current-url-in-magento-2/) solution, but not working.

My Sample URL: https://magento.com/questions-sample
Expected Data to get: `questions-sample`

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the request path, then you can use this code:

```
$this->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo()
```

And if you need a query string included as well, then this one:

```
$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
<?php

namespace <Vendor>\<Module>\Block;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
 
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
     StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
     array $data = []
     ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
     }

    public function getCurrentUrl() {
     return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
    }
}
```